# When should a type be a struct containing another type and when should it just "extend"(?) that type?

Tags: types, struct, go

I'm currently learning Go by doing the [rosalind problems](http://rosalind.info) (basically a bunch of bioinformatics related code katas).

I'm currently representing a DNA strand with a type:

```
type DNAStrand struct {
    dna byte[]
}
```

My initial reason was to encapsulate the byte slice so I would know it only contained bytes representing the nucleotides: `'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'`. I realized that this was obviously not guarateed since I could simply do:

```
DNAStrand{[]byte("foo bar")}
```

And there is no longer any guarantee that my dna strand contains a byte array with only elements from those four bytes.

Since my struct only contains a byte array is it better/more ideomatic to do:

```
type DNAStrand []byte
```

Or is it better to let the type contain the dna strand? Are there any rules of thumb for when to use either of the two approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struct with zero fields are handy. Structs with many fields are handy even more. Structs with exactly one field are a bit special and I can't think of a reasonably "good" case where to use them - even though they are seen regularly "in the wild". I, for one, don't use them.

Anyway, if you really really need tighter/bulletproof safety about the `DNAStrand` slice content - then it is possible to to use the single field struct and define an argument checking setter method for this/such named type.

In that case, if the definition is later used from some other package, there's no way, modulo using [package unsafe](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/), to circumvent the checks and get a result equivalent to your `DNAStrand{[]byte("foo bar")}` example.

Comment: But wouldn't it still be possible to do `DNAStrand{[]byte("foo bar")}` from another package? Or can I not create structs with non-exported fields (like `DNAStrand`) from outside the package it resides?

Comment: Yes, that _is_ possible. I should have been more precise: ... then there would be no _accidental_ way to circumvent things ... The `v := DNAStrand{[]byte("foo bar")}` is, at least to me, a case where it is _intended_ to assign that value to an instance. In contrast to, say `v.Set(foo())` and a bug in `foo` returns an "illegal" value.

Comment: @jnml I can't test right now, but I thought that it was an error (barring compiler bugs or tricks) to try and directly assign a value to an unexported field from a different package

Comment: @PaoloFalabella: Now I'm confused^2. This example http://play.golang.org/p/VU3yh_45Xj made me think what I wrote in my first comment above, but those fields actually are not _unexported_. Shame on me, I cannot figure right now from the top of my head what's correct, so I should check it with code :-(

Comment: Tried a simple case of this now and got the following error: `implicit assignment of unexported field 'a' in a.A literal`. So in essence having a unexported field in a struct protect it from being created from outside that package...

Comment: @EmilH: Good news. It also means the answer is correct - and that I had an quite idiotic moment in my first comment B-)

Answer (score 11):

Taking your specific example I would probably do something like this:

```
type neucleotide char // unexported type users can't construct their own.

type DNAStrand []neucleotide // because users can't construct their own
                             // nucleotides they also can't construct their
                             // own DNAStrands.

const (
  // These are exported values so they can use these nucleotides to construct a
  // DNAStrand with.
  A nucleotide = 'A'
  C nucleotide = 'C'
  G nudleotide = 'G'
  T nucleotide = 'T'
)

// This function allows them to actually construct a DNAstrand with a list of
//  nucleotides from the constants above.
func New(nts ...nucleotide) DNAStrand {
    return nts
}
```

Since the nucleotide type is not exported users can't construct their own. You provide the only allowed instances of them in the exported consts so no user can provide their own new nucleotides.

Comment: I initially started doing it this way, but got stuck when I wanted to a nucleotide to be able to give me it's compliment (`A <-> T, C <-> G`). Now that I know more about unexported types I think I could let nucleotide be an unexported interface and create unexported types for each of the nucleotides... Then as you demonstrate expose them as constants. Might be overkill, but then I like to have types for everything :) Kudos!

Comment: Even further, if the # of DNAStrands is going to be large and pose a memory problem, you can encode them not in their ASCII form, but in a compressed form using Huffman coding - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding - I do this for a SmallHand type (in a card game to keep track of which cards are in the hand) - https://github.com/mzimmerman/sdzpinochle/blob/master/pinochle.go#L91

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `type DNAStrand []byte` because it's simple, and because I can use regexps on it. I'd probably use an initialisation function that checks that every byte is in ACGT though.

```
var validDNAStrandPat = regexp.MustCompile("[ACTG]*")

func DNAStrandForString(s string) DNAStrand {
    if !validDNAStrandPat.Match(s) {
        panic("Invalid DNA Strand.")
    }
    return DNAStrand([]byte(s))
}
```