# How do I do enums in golang?

Tags: go

I have

```
const (
  BlahFoo = 1 << iota
  MooFoo
)
```

then

```
type Cluster struct {
  a  int
  b  int
}
```

I want Cluster.a to only be BlahFoo or MooFoo

How do I enforce that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an idiomatic way of representing enums in golang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426366/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-of-representing-enums-in-golang)

Comment: There's no way to enforce the value in Go, except via accessor methods to check the value for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
type FooEnum int

const (
  BlahFoo FooEnum = 1 << iota
  MooFoo
)

type Cluster struct {
  a FooEnum
  b int
}
```

Comment: This is probably best you can get. Will still allow you for `Cluster{a: 10}`, but at least would break on `x := 10; Cluster{a: x}`.