# How to take ownership of Any:downcast_ref from trait object?

Tags: rust

I've met a conflict with Rust's ownership rules and a trait object downcast. This is a sample:

```
use std::any::Any;
trait Node{
    fn gen(&self) -> Box<Node>;
}

struct TextNode;
impl Node for TextNode{
    fn gen(&self) -> Box<Node>{
        Box::new(TextNode)
    }
}

fn main(){
    let mut v: Vec<TextNode> = Vec::new();
    let node = TextNode.gen();
    let foo = &node as &Any;
    match foo.downcast_ref::<TextNode>(){
        Some(n) => {
            v.push(*n);
        },
        None => ()
    };

}
```

The `TextNode::gen` method has to return `Box<Node>` instead of `Box<TextNode>`, so I have to downcast it to `Box<TextNode>`.

`Any::downcast_ref`'s return value is `Option<&T>`, so I can't take ownership of the downcast result and push it to `v`.

====edit=====

As I am not good at English, my question is vague.

[I am implementing](https://github.com/shahuwang/Rustparse/blob/master/src/parse/node.rs) (copying may be more precise) the template parser in Go standard library.

What I really need is a vector, `Vec<Box<Node>>` or `Vec<Box<Any>>`, which can contain `TextNode`, `NumberNode`, `ActionNode`, any type of node that implements the trait `Node` can be pushed into it.

Every node type needs to implement the `copy` method, return `Box<Any>`, and then downcasting to the concrete type is OK. But to copy `Vec<Box<Any>>`, as you don't know the concrete type of every element, you have to check one by one, that is really inefficient.

If the copy method returns `Box<Node>`, then copying `Vec<Box<Node>>` is simple. But it seems that there is no way to get the concrete type from trait object.

Comment: could you please link the original in Go you're trying to port? I'm not familiar with it

Comment: Hi, Go code is in https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/text/template/parse/node.go, the struct `ListNode` has a field `Nodes [] Node` , it can contains all the node structs that implement `interface Node`, and you can get the concrete type with type assertion http://blog.denevell.org/golang-interface-type-assertions-switch.html,

Comment: In Rust I would go with the `enum` approach I gave in the answer, as a starting point. [Go does not really have enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426366/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-of-representing-enums-in-golang), so they insert a `NodeType` to be able to tell if a node is a `PipeNode` or an `ActionNode`. You don't need that in Rust. Also Go [does not have generics and uses interfaces and type switches for most of their use cases](https://golang.org/doc/faq#generics). I'd say to give it a try with enum and come back to ask questions if you're stuck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you control `trait Node` you can have it return a `Box<Any>` and use the [Box::downcast](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) method

It would look like this:

```
use std::any::Any;
trait Node {
    fn gen(&self) -> Box<Any>; // downcast works on Box<Any>
}

struct TextNode;

impl Node for TextNode {
    fn gen(&self) -> Box<Any> {
        Box::new(TextNode)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<TextNode> = Vec::new();
    let node = TextNode.gen();

    if let Ok(n) = node.downcast::<TextNode>() {
        v.push(*n);
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, you should not jump to using `Any`. I know it looks familiar when coming from a language with subtype polymorphism and want to recreate a hierarchy of types with some root type (like in this case: you're trying to recreate the `TextNode is a Node` relationship and create a `Vec` of Nodes). I did it too and so did many others: I bet the number of SO questions on `Any` outnumbers the times `Any` is actually used on crates.io.

While `Any` does have its uses, in Rust it has alternatives.
In case you have not looked at them, I wanted to make sure you considered doing this with:

### enums

Given different Node types you can express the "a Node is any of these types" relationship with an enum:

```
struct TextNode;
struct XmlNode;
struct HtmlNode;

enum Node {
    Text(TextNode),
    Xml(XmlNode),
    Html(HtmlNode),
}
```

With that you can put them all in one `Vec` and do different things depending on the variant, without downcasting:

```
let v: Vec<Node> = vec![
    Node::Text(TextNode),
    Node::Xml(XmlNode),
    Node::Html(HtmlNode)];

for n in &v {
    match n {
        &Node::Text(_) => println!("TextNode"),
        &Node::Xml(_) => println!("XmlNode"),
        &Node::Html(_) => println!("HtmlNode"),
    }
}
```

[playground](http://is.gd/aeBWBQ)

adding a variant means potentially changing your code in many places: the enum itself and all the functions that do something with the enum (to add the logic for the new variant). But then again, with `Any` it's mostly the same, all those functions might need to add the downcast to the new variant.

### Trait objects (not Any)

You can try putting the actions you'd want to perform on the various types of nodes in the trait, so you don't need to downcast, but just call methods on the trait object.
This is essentially what you were doing, except putting the method on the Node trait instead of downcasting.

[playground](http://is.gd/KnoYN2)

Comment: I edited my post, thanks to you , I find another solution.

Comment: @WangRuiqi it's a very dangerous solution (transmute is unsafe for a reason)... But just out of curiosity, why do you want to return a trait object `Box<Node>` instead of simply `Box<Self>` and avoid all downcasting, like [in this example](http://is.gd/IoZT8l)?

Comment: Actually I need another struct `ListNode` which contains a vector of `TextNode`, `NumberNode`, `ActionNode`, etc. If return `Box<Self>`,  I have no idea to implement the `ListNode`

Comment: Why it is danger as I already know these two type could be scalar casted?

Comment: @WangRuiqi I suggest you have a read to the [transmutes section of the Rustnomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/transmutes.html)

Comment: Thank you，I made a mistake in my code and I thought it work so I post a sample without check. I deleted my answer.

Comment: @WangRuiqi since my original answer seems not to address your original need, I tried giving you a couple of alternatives to using Any

Comment: Hi，This disscusion https://users.rust-lang.org/t/trait-objects-with-associated-types/746/21 seem to address my need. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f7137355d1e6eaf6aed9&version=stable

Comment: Your solution is good, too! I edit my question for more detail about my nedd.

Answer (score 3):

The (more) ideomatic way for the problem:

```rust
use std::any::Any;

pub trait Nodeable {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct TextNode {}

impl Nodeable for TextNode {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn Nodeable>> = Vec::new();
    let node = TextNode {};  // or impl TextNode::new

    v.push(Box::new(node));

    // the downcast back to TextNode could be solved like this:
    if let Some(b) = v.pop() {  // only if we have a node…
        let n = (*b).as_any().downcast_ref::<TextNode>().unwrap();  // this is secure *)
        println!("{:?}", n);
    };
}
```

*) This is secure: only `Nodeable`s are allowd to be downcasted to types that had `Nodeable` implemented.