# How to move the concrete value out of a Box<dyn Any>?

Tags: rust

I have value of type `T` in `value: Box<dyn Any>` and want to extract it. The only way I found is this:

```
let pv = value.downcast_mut::<T>();
let v = std::mem::replace(pv, T::default());
```

Is there a way to get `v` without requiring `T` to implement `Default`?

Comment: The suggested solution does not compile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Box` has its own [`downcast`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) which returns a `Result<Box<T>, Box<dyn Any>>`. Once you have a `Box<T>` you can simply dereference it to get the `T` out. Here's one way to use it:

```
fn get<T: Any>(value: Box<dyn Any>) -> T {
    let pv = value.downcast().expect("The pointed-to value must be of type T");
    *pv
}
```

See also:

- [How do I get an owned value out of a `Box`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42264041/155423)
- [How to take ownership of Any:downcast_ref from trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34922579/3650362)