# ENUMs for custom types in GO

Tags: go, enums, iota

I am trying to generate an enum for a type I defined

```
type FeeStage int
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426366/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-of-representing-enums-in-golang) I learned that I can use iota to create an enum based on this type

```
const(
     Stage1 FeeStage = iota
     Stage2 
     Stage3
)
```

However, manipulating the actual values of the enum is rather cumbersome and error prone

```
const(
     Stage1 FeeStage = iota           // 0
     Stage2          = iota + 6       // 7
     Stage3          = (iota - 3) * 5 // -5
)
```

Is there a way to automatically convert a list of ENUMs with custom values to a certain type. This is what I was using before but only converts the first member of the constant to the custom type.

```
const(
     Stage1 FeeStage = 1
     Stage2          = 2
     Stage3          = 2
)
```

[Here](http://play.golang.org/p/J8s6uchndh) is a playground with a similar result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an idiomatic way of representing enums in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426366/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-of-representing-enums-in-go)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way beyond either using `iota` and automatic enums, or doing the most straightforward thing:

```
const(
     Stage1 FeeStage = 1
     Stage2 FeeStage = 2

     // or another syntax with same results
     Stage3 = FeeStage(2)
)
```

which IMHO is less cumbersome than doing stuff like `iota + 5` which as you said is really bad.

I usually either use iota if the value is not important beyond the context of the program, or explicit typing if I need the values to be used in a protocol or something.

Though I have to say sometimes just using ints or strings is good enough, it depends on the context. See for example the [http status codes in the standard library](https://golang.org/src/net/http/status.go). They don't have a special type.

Comment: Or without syntax just "const Stage1 = 1; varOfTypeFeeStage = Stage1" can also work in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

You should maybe clarify what you're actually wanting to do with enumerated constants, but it looks like you're trying to assign arbitrary values to your custom type.

Using `iota` doesn't need to be cumbersome if you structure your constants and the initialization to be ordered and to follow a pattern.  [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#constants) has a section on this too.

You can create fairly complicated patterns for enumerated constants, which doesn't have to be error-prone and cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's a way. But let's clear some things first.

In [constant declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_declarations), if the type is present, the constant will take the specified type:

```
const n int64 = 3 // n will be a typed constant, its type will be int64
```

If the type is omitted, the constant will take the type of the expression:

```
const x = int16(3) // x will be a typed constant, its type will be int16
```

If the expression is an untyped constant, the declared constant will remain untyped constant:

```
const i = 1 // i will be an untyped integer constant
```

Note that if you try to print `i`'s type (e.g. with `fmt.Printf("%T", i)`, you will see `int`, and that's because when passing a constant to a function or when assigning it to a variable, it has to be converted to an actual type, and the default type will be used (because `fmt.Println()` has arguments type of `interface{}`) - which is `int` for an untyped integer constant.

Within a parenthesized `const` declaration list the expression list may be omitted from declarations (except at the first). If the expression is missing, the previous non-empty expression will be used (textual substitution).

So when you do this:

```
const(
    Stage1 FeeStage = iota
    Stage2 
    Stage3
)
```

It means:

```
const (
    Stage1 FeeStage = iota
    Stage2 FeeStage = iota
    Stage3 FeeStage = iota
)
```

Which results in 3 new constants: `Stage1`, `Stage2` and `Stage3`, all being of type `FreeStage`.

Your second example:

```
const (
    Stage1 FeeStage = iota           // 0
    Stage2          = iota + 6       // 7
    Stage3          = (iota - 3) * 5 // -5
)
```

Since you didn't omit the expressions, **ONLY** your first constant `Stage1` will be a typed constant (of type `FreeStage`), the rest will be untyped constants! So this doesn't even qualify (doesn't comply with your requirements)!

And now to your point: you want something like this:

```
const(
    Stage1 FeeStage = 1
    Stage2          = 2
    Stage3          = 2
)
```

As stated above, if you leave out the type, `Stage2` and `Stage3` will be untyped constants. So type must be specified, you may take advantage of the fact that a const specification is:

```
ConstSpec      = IdentifierList [ [ Type ] "=" ExpressionList ] .
```

You may specify an identifier *list*:

```
const(
    Stage1, Stage2, Stage3 FeeStage = 1, 2, 2
)
```

Is this more readable? Maybe if there are a few constants only. If there are many, use Not_a_Golfer's recommendation:

```
const(
    Stage1 FeeStage = 1
    Stage2 FeeStage = 2
    Stage3 FeeStage = 2
)
```

Comment: that's a nice touch, but feels less readable to me personally - I think 2-3 consts is the limit for this being useful. and at 2-3 it's really nothing repeating the type. but it's a matter of taste. anyways, great answer!

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I agree. I wouldn't use it myself, I would put it in 3 lines. But it's a possibility.