# What is idiomatic way to get string representation of enum in Go?

Tags: go

If I have an enum:

```
type Day int8

const (
    Monday Day = iota
    Tuesday
    ...
    Sunday
)
```

What is more *natural* *Go* way to get string of it?

fucntion:

```
func ToString(day Day) string {
   ...
}
```

or method

```
func (day Day) String() string  {
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://blog.golang.org/generate
It may be more apt for your use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an idiomatic way of representing enums in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426366/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-of-representing-enums-in-go)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second one is more idiomatic because it satisfies [Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface.

```
func (day Day) String() string  {
    ... 
}
```

We declare this method on the `Day` type not `*Day` type because we are not changing the value.

It will enable you to write.

```
fmt.Println(day)
```

and get the value produced by `String` method.

Comment: Thanks, Grzegorz Żur. I follow that way. But there is another point of view: if we don't change type state  - better to declare function.

Comment: @SergiiGetman Could explain this part better "we don't change type state"?

Comment: Grzegorz Żur. I ma newbie in go and can be wrong. But idea is if we have type, for example `struct`. and we have some piece of code that change that struct it is better to make it method of that type. if we just `use` the type we can make fucntion

Comment: Please see [Should I define methods on values or pointers?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)

Answer (score 7):

The easy way for you to answer this question yourself is to look at the Go standard library.

---

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> [type Weekday](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Weekday)
>
> A Weekday specifies a day of the week (Sunday = 0, ...).
>
> ```
> type Weekday int
>
> const (
>         Sunday Weekday = iota
>         Monday
>         Tuesday
>         Wednesday
>         Thursday
>         Friday
>         Saturday
> )
> ```
>
> func (Weekday) String
>
> ```
> func (d Weekday) String() string
> ```
>
> String returns the English name of the day ("Sunday", "Monday", ...).

`src/time/time.go`:

```
// A Weekday specifies a day of the week (Sunday = 0, ...).

type Weekday int

const (
    Sunday Weekday = iota
    Monday
    Tuesday
    Wednesday
    Thursday
    Friday
    Saturday
)

var days = [...]string{
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
}

// String returns the English name of the day ("Sunday", "Monday", ...).
func (d Weekday) String() string {
    if Sunday <= d && d <= Saturday {
        return days[d]
    }
    buf := make([]byte, 20)
    n := fmtInt(buf, uint64(d))
    return "%!Weekday(" + string(buf[n:]) + ")"
}
```

---

> [Package fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> ```
> import "fmt"
> ```
>
> [type Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer)
>
> Stringer is implemented by any value that has a String method, which
>   defines the “native” format for that value. The String method is used
>   to print values passed as an operand to any format that accepts a
>   string or to an unformatted printer such as Print.
>
> ```
> type Stringer interface {
>         String() string
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer might have performance hit but when working with a huge set of enums, having a mapping would be a terrible ideatype Category string

```
type Category string

const (
    AllStocks        Category = "all"
    WatchList        Category = "watch_list"
    TopGainer        Category = "top_gainer_stock"
    TopLoser         Category = "top_loser_stock"
    FiftyTwoWeekHigh Category = "high_stocks"
    FiftyTwoWeekLow  Category = "low_stocks"
    HotStocks        Category = "hot_stock"
    MostTraded       Category = "most_active_stock"
)

func (c Category) toString() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", c)
}
```

This is the easiest string formatting route for enums.