# How to use enums in go?

Tags: go

is there a simple implementation of enums in golang?
Something like the following?

```
type status enum[string] {
    pending = "PENDING"
    active = "ACTIVE"
}
```

Comment: https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/golang-const-type-enums-iota-bc4befd096d3

Answer (score 20):

```
const (
    statusPending = "PENDING"
    statusActive  = "ACTIVE"
)
```

Or, application of the example at [Ultimate Visual Guide to Go Enums](https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/golang-const-type-enums-iota-bc4befd096d3)

```
// Declare a new type named status which will unify our enum values
// It has an underlying type of unsigned integer (uint).
type status int

// Declare typed constants each with type of status
const (
    pending status = iota
    active
)

// String returns the string value of the status
func (s status) String() string {
    strings := [...]string{"PENDING", "ACTIVE"}

    // prevent panicking in case of status is out-of-range
    if s < pending || s > active {
        return "Unknown"
    }

    return strings[s]
}
```

Comment: Duplicating the underlying string values here. Kind of a bummer

Comment: @JohnAllen yeah, that's what I'm looking to avoid as well.

Answer (score 5):

> Something like the following?

Not yet

Read here [What is an idiomatic way of representing enums in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426366/what-is-an-idiomatic-way-of-representing-enums-in-go)

Comment: allow me to provide some of language's author code regarding "enums": https://golang.org/src/net/http/status.go